# Cannot convert an iterator directly off of a for loop in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use a for loop with an iterator to extract all the values of member fields of a case class and for use within my system, but need it to be in the format of a `Seq[String]`. I'm wondering why this works:

```
case class MyClass(field1:String, field2:Int){

  def toSeqString: Seq[String] = {
    val stringIter = for (field <- this.productIterator) yield {
      val changedField = // do some work on 'field'
     changedField.toString
    } 
    // stringIter is of type Iterator[String] at this point
    stringIter.toSeq
  }

}
```

But this doesn't:

```
case class MyClass(field1:String, field2:Int){

  def toSeqString: Seq[String] = {
    for (field <- this.productIterator) yield {
      val changedField = // do some work on 'field'
     changedField.toString
    }.toSeq // have also tried .to[collection.immutable.Seq]
  }

}
```

The error saying that the result of the second example is an `Iterator[Seq[Char]]`, and not a `Seq[String]`. Why do I need to extract the result of my for loop to a val, rather than directly chain it off the completion of the for-yield loop? It would seem I'm doing the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply a parenthesis issue.

You want:

```
def toSeqString: Seq[String] = {
  (for (field <- this.productIterator) yield {
    val changedField = // do some work on 'field'
   changedField.toString
  }).toSeq
}
```

Note the extra parenthesis around `for`. Otherwise `.toSeq` is applied on the block after `yield` - therefore making the `String` a `Seq[Char]`.

As a side note, you may want to simply do:

```
this.productIterator.map(p => ...).toSeq
```